# Date and Time Saving via any method

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to make an app for a friend of mine who is a hardcore workout junkie, and I'm stuck on one part of the app.

I'm attempting to make it automatically save the date and time of every single one of his workouts, so he can look back and see the last time he worked out and how often he did over the month and things like that.

However, I have no idea how to go about this. My knowledge of SharedPreferences is subpar, and I am unable to integrate Google Calendar. Is there any other way for something like this to happen?

If not, could someone help me with the SharedPreferences portion?

Thank you.

Comment: if you want to store data for a month use db instead of maintaining data in SharedPreference.

Comment: @sumit ok sorry that was my fault for being unclear. When I said month it was just an example of time. I actually want it to save forever.

Comment: then you should go for database because SharedPreference is used for storing small chunk of data for a little while like maintaining a session.

Comment: @sumit oh alright thank you. Would u be willing to tell me how that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have created a design for you. you can make necessary changes according to your requirement.

```
//Create a dbHelper class like this

public class DatabaseNew extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "DataBase";

    public DatabaseNew(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Module1";
    private static final String USERTABLE = "USER_INFO";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String WORKOUT = "WORKOUT";
    private static final String WORKOUT_TIME = "WORKOUT_TIME";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + USERTABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + WORKOUT + " TEXT,"
            + WORKOUT_TIME + " TEXT"+");";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USERTABLE;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Inside onCreate: creating table");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
    }

    //to save workout name and time in db
    public void saveData(String workout, String time){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
        data.put(WORKOUT,workout);
        data.put(WORKOUT_TIME,time);
        db.insert(USERTABLE,null,data);
        db.close();
    }

    //to get workout name and time from db
    public List<HashMap<String,String>> getData(){
        List<HashMap<String,String>> userData = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + USERTABLE ;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String,String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
                dataMap.put(WORKOUT,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORKOUT)));
                dataMap.put(WORKOUT_TIME,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORKOUT_TIME)));
                userData.add(dataMap);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return userData;

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Inside onUpgrade");
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

//Then inside your activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        //Initializing the db
        DatabaseNew db = new DatabaseNew(this);
        //sending dummy data you can send actual workout and time like this
        db.saveData("pull up","30 mins");
        db.saveData("push up","40 mins");
        db.saveData("Leg up","30 mins");
        db.saveData("crunches","30 mins");
        db.saveData("Bench Press","30 mins");

        //to retrieve data from data base
        List<HashMap<String,String>> data = db.getData();
        for (HashMap<String,String> a : data){
            Log.e("TestActivity"," "+"Workout : "+a.get("WORKOUT")
                    +" "+"Time : "+a.get("WORKOUT_TIME"));
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This actually helps a lot.